# Which member of the Icelandic national football team designed a board game?

Tags: identify-this-game

I was just watching Argentina play Iceland in the football World Cup, and one of the ITV commentators mentioned as an aside that one of the players on the Iceland team had recently published a board game, but I didn't catch which player they were referring to. Does anyone know which player this was, and what the board game is?

Comment: Wow, down-voting this question is pretty harsh  It's absolutely on topic, surely.

Comment: It may have been downvoted due to lack of apparent research effort.

Comment: Which always seemed like a weird rationale to me because now Googling the question produces this question as the top result for me. The question was harder to Google before this question, and now it's easier to Google. It's a net win for the internet!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I loath football but this seemed googleable.  I got the list of players from wikipedia and searched each one with 'board game' until it turned up  [this](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2010386/johann-berg-gudmundsson-board-game) BGG thread.

The player is Jóhann Berg Guðmundsson who designed a trivia game called. [Beint í Mark](https://www.beintimark.is/).

Comment: Thanks! (Looking at the timings, I think that BGG thread didn't exist when I was searching for an answer earlier...)

Comment: No problem,  I'd have asked here as well if I wanted to know something and google wasn't giving answer at the time.  I mean if I'd googled and found nothing i'd just not have posted an answer!